# How we make iso of current changed kernel

Tags: 14.04, playonlinux

How we make iso image of current modified kernel.I want to create my own iso image  file for vm which run on low specs like ubuntolite

Comment: Use the debian-live scripts, it is in the repos

Comment: is there any software for create iso i don't know how to use debian-live scripts..I see the link for it but i am failed to create the iso

Comment: IMHO the debian live script are the easiest, best maintained, and most reliable. Either way, there is typically a bit of reading involved if you wish to learn how to make a custom iso. If you read this you should be a working CD, then tweak http://debian-live.alioth.debian.org/live-manual/stable/manual/html/live-manual.en.html

Comment: I am following that link http://willhaley.com/blog/create-a-custom-debian-stretch-live-environment-ubuntu-17-zesty/ but i failed to create iso file.The link which u provide it has many detail i dont understand which data is used to create iso

Comment: i try system back and through terminal i create iso but there is an error not working

Comment: plz give the proper way according to which i got my output

Comment: the link I gave you runs through how to make a live iso. If you have a specific question about a specific part, I can help. If you follow some other method your are on your own AFIK.

Comment: i download a kernel in this kernel i change something now i want to make iso of it but with debian live this not achieved

Comment: There is a whole section on kernels - http://debian-live.alioth.debian.org/live-manual/stable/manual/html/live-manual.en.html#435 . If you wish to make a custom iso you will need to do a lot of reading, there is a steep learning curve. I have made a ton of custom iso and I am telling you the debian live scripts are the easiest way and this is not the place to write all that stuff out. If you have a specific question about a specific step that would be different.

Comment: You can also read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch but I will again tell you, those pages are not as reliable and paradoxically take you longer, although they may yield a quick fix.

Comment: ok thanks u soo much @panther i will try to find out the solution.I make iso but not working becuase i am not successfully add dependencies i make iso using system back

Comment: I understand. Read through the 2 Ubuntu  links I gave you. If there is some command you do not understand, google search and read a bit on that command. Work through the debian live page. Start at the top and work your way to the bottom. Make sure your custom kernel boots on as wide a range of hardware as possible or at least your target hardware. Read how to make your kernel into a .deb https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile . As you can see your question is very broad.